# Change expire of bundled file mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I've been searching around for a way to change from the default behavior of adding 1 year to expires-header to a lower number but i cannot find anything. It seems as it is not treated as a static file, and therefore render the possibility of using clientCache in staticFile in web.config obsolete. IBundleTransform cannot be used since it is not run on every request, but while doing the actual bundling.

Anyone have any idea what to do?